# how to get id of a background process from Linux shell in C (not PID)

Tags: linux, shell

I mean, when I put sleep 30 into background, something will be printed on the screen like:

```
[50] 4410
```

I know that 4410 is the pid, and I can get it with waitpid(). But my question is how can I get that 40?

Comment: are you talking about background process created with [`fork`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) ?

Comment: yes, but not the pid

Comment: It's a job id internal to the shell. If your program is not sh or bash or csh or anything like that, you don't have this number.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you very much. May I ask how can I get that job id in c when I use execvp() to execute cmd? I know how to get pid by using waitpid, but not for a job id

Comment: There is no job when you use execvp(), accordingly there's no job id. Jobs are something that shells do. Cheers!

Comment: You are definitely mixing *apples* and *oranges*. Why would you think you could get a *job id* though C? Moreover, what are you looking to do with a job ID in C to begin with that you cannot do with a PID? This seems a lot like an X-Y question.

Comment: OT: The moment `waitpid()` returns you a specific PID, the process is dead.

Comment: Are you asking because you're writing your own shell? If so, the approximate algorithm for assigning a jobid is: if there are no existing background processes for this shell, give it jobid 1. Otherwise, give it a jobid larger than any existing jobid. If the user creates a pipeline of processes, the pipeline uses just a single jobid.

Comment: Which 40 you are asking for? I see a 30, a 50 and a 4410 but no 40 in your post.

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It seems that you have several misunderstandings. See also [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) (use it to experiment, e.g. `strace` some shell process and some commands) and [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)